# Facebook page tab prompting for login, but it shouldn't

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

When a user is not logged in and they navigate to a page tab made with our app, they get an obtrusive dialog asking them to log in:

This has nothing to do with http vs https, the app is not in sandbox mode, there is nothing in the tab asking for a login or user information, etc. I've gone through the app settings at least a half dozen times now, and nothing is wrong there. Aside of urls, the settings are identical to another app I have that does not suffer from this problem. I'm stumped!

Edit: here is an affected tab: https://www.facebook.com/StaticHtmlThunderpenny/app_203351739677351

[image: Popup that says "Not Logged In - Please log in to continue."]

Comment: What happens when you debug the page? at what point is the 'Not logged in' dialog triggered? Are you definitely making no calls at all to the API in your app's code?

Answer (score 2):

This message is *not* about login *to your app*, but Facebook in general.

So my guess would be that the *page* your app is installed as page tab app on is **restricted** in some way – by age, location, or for having alcohol-related content. And then of course Facebook asks for login, because otherwise they can not determine whether or not the (as of now still “anonymous”) user qualifies to see the page.

So go check the *page* settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Christoph! Unfortunately that's not what's going on here -- on one page, my app triggers the login dialog, and other apps don't. Still, I double checked the page settings, and nothing there in any way restricts access. :/

Comment: I believe it could be a Facebook bug as some of my page tab apps are doing the same even if I copy the content from a page tab that works without logging in.

Comment: Yeah, I'm leaning towards the bug theory now as well. Bother. :/

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not app related question.

This is thumb rule!! To access any app on Facebook, you need to log in to Facebook. You can see Facebook page without log in. But for facebook apps, you should be authentic user.

Comment: Thanks, @somnath-muluk! That's not the issue here, though. Page tabs are a special kind of app, and other page tab apps don't require a login. Just this one. :/

Answer (score 0):

with this issue in my own experience that I came across some years back with a facebook app that I was running, if this doesn't relate to any of your other social networking apps then am aligning two set of possibilities and solution.

1. The user might have not properly logged out as "written" in the app for the users logout stage.

   - Solution would be that the user logout as expected before closing the app.
2. The user might have set up an automatic login prompt which was removed by the app when it was been updated automatically. (If you do get me???)

   - Solution would be to monitise your app on updates and login informations or better still just login and logout ask intended by the app and for security reasons.

Lastly I would say that automatic bookmark database should be added to the server part so current pages as the user uses the app would be saved after logout or login stage. Thank you, hope this helps and if not let me know what am missing.